# MVC - how to display a news article into a view with formatting

Tags: html, model-view-controller, formatting

I am new to MVC, and so practicing building a website. I have created a database and in one of my tables I have a column that is a varchar which contains my news article. I want to display this article on my webpage (it has 800 words). I am currently looping through my records in the table and populating the data, but my issue is that I want to display the article in following format. how would I do this? Do I create extra columns to store the data in or do I call the entire column in like @Model.Article[i].MainText and create a controller that formats the string and then passes it back to the view?  Any help/guidance would be massively appreciated as i am stuck!

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="blogdata">
        <span class="firstcharacter">T</span> text text text ......
        <br>
        <br> more text more text
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="blog-short-info">
           Text more text                                                      
        </div>
        <br> more text more text
        <br> more text more text
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="blogdata">                                                
           Text more text more text
           <br>
           <br> 
           <br>
            <br> more text
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the extra columns, you can use Substring in Razor View. Something like this:

```
@foreach(var article in Model.Article)
{    
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="blogdata">
      <span class="firstcharacter">@article.MainText.Substring(0,1)</span>
      <span>@article.MainText.Substring(1,100)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

and so on.

You could also generate a new member to pass from the controller to the view and display it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The only issue I see with substring is that not all articles will be of the same length so that could cut off some of the article at the wrong point. What do you mean by generating a new member to pass from the controller?

Comment: In the partial class that was generated from the model add a new object. It will not contain any database data but your predefined data. So in the partial class Article (Article.cs) add something you need (string firstParagraph {get; set;} string secondParagraph {get; set;} and then in the controller before sending the data to the view just populate it dynamically.